# Help finding the length of a line inside a rectangle.

Tags: geometry

I need the formula to calculate the length of the red line in the image attached. I always have the point that starts the line and the angle is always 45° but I don't know how to calculate the length.
[check the shape here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RynQq.jpg)

I apologize that my description is not enough, I just don't know how to explain it better. That is why I draw the shape.
Thank you.

Comment: Hint: Pythagoras' theorem.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  It's the hypotenuse of a $45^\circ-45^\circ-90^\circ$ triangle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method-1(Pythagoras): $H^2 = B^2 + P^2$
where H(Hypotenuse) is the side opposite to the right angle and B and P are the other two sides.
We have red line as hypotenuse. As the angle is 45 so other is also 45 and both sides are equal(sides opposite to same angle are equal).
So putting them in formulae we get:
$$H^2=2^2+2^2$$
$$H=2\sqrt{2}$$

Method-2(Trigonometry): We can use $\cos$ function.
We have $\cos 45 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.
So $$\frac 2H = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$
$$H=2\sqrt{2}$$
If you don't know about Trigonometric functions please refer:https://www.mathsisfun.com/sine-cosine-tangent.html

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Construct another similar triangle to the first one. Its area is $\frac{1}{2} (4)(2) = 4$, but $\frac{1}{2} (h)(h) = 4$ where $h$ is the hypotenuse of the old triangle. This means $h^2 = 8 \Rightarrow h = \sqrt{8} = \sqrt{2^2 \cdot 2} = 2 \sqrt{2}$.

Alternatively, by similar triangles, $\frac{2}{h} = \frac{h}{4} \Rightarrow h^2 = 8$ again.